# PySpark Groupby Filtering with Condition

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, etl, user-defined-functions

I am working on the structured dataframe in pyspark. The data is read the parquet format from s3. Then, I would like to filter out some data with the condition.
For example:

```
Data:
key_1  value rec_date
  A     1    2020-01-01
  A     2    2020-01-02
  A    10    2020-01-03
  B    10    2020-10-10
  B    10    2020-10-11
  B    10    2020-10-12
```

```
Filter Condition:
{"A":{'abnormal_daterange':[('2020-01-01', '2020-01-02'), ('2020-02-01', '2020-02-04')]},
"B": {'abnormal_daterange':[('2020-10-10', '2020-10-11')]}
}
```

```
Expected result:
key_1  value rec_date
  A    10    2020-01-03
  B    10    2020-10-12
```

I know I can use `@pandas-udf` to create the function to `group by` and filter with the condition, but I would like to simplify the code and don't over-engineer.

Do any structured data frame `filter` / build-in function can EFFICIENTLY filter out the data with the condition?

Comment: How large is the filter condition? If it is small enough you could turn it into a data frame and use left anti join.

Comment: @etherealyn I have edited the filter condition, and it can be multiple conditions.

Comment: @Hong if the dict is not very big, you can convert it into an SQL expression including (AND, OR etc) to hold the filtering logic and then do df.filter() using this SQL expression.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have `df` and `filterDf`:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ("A", "1", "2020-01-01"),
        ("A", "2", "2020-01-02"),
        ("A", "10", "2020-01-03"),
        ("B", "10", "2020-10-10"),
        ("B", "10", "2020-10-11"),
        ("B", "10", "2020-10-12")
    ],
    ['key_1', 'value', 'rec_date']
)

filterDf = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ("A", "2020-01-01", "2020-01-02"),
        ("B", "2020-10-01", "2020-10-11")
    ],
    ["key", "start_date", "end_date"]
)
```

Then you can use left anti join to filter your `df` against contents of `filterDf`:

```py
res = df.join(
    filterDf.hint("broadcast"),
    (col("key_1") == col("key")) & (col("rec_date").between(col("start_date"), col("end_date"))),
    "leftanti"
)
```

The result will be:

```
+-----+-----+----------+
|key_1|value|  rec_date|
+-----+-----+----------+
|    A|   10|2020-01-03|
|    B|   10|2020-10-12|
+-----+-----+----------+
```

Afterwards, you can apply your `groupBy` aggregations.